# Android app only runs after minimizing

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm trying to make an Android snake game, and I want to have a grid that stretches in a square the width of the screen (Portrait).

I an using a drawable storing my `png`, and when i add the line `grid.setBounds(0,0,screenWidth,screenWidth)` my phone displays a white screen at first, though it works as expected once I minimize and reopen my application.

The app also works as expected if I put standard numbers in as parameters. This is on my nexus 6P on android 7. When I emulate it on an older device it works, but emulated on a newer device, I see the same issue. I get the screen width as follows:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
screenWidth = size.x;
screenHeight = size.y;
scale = screenWidth/1024.0;
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the screen size in `onWindowFocusChnaged` method of activity.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;
    scale = screenWidth/1024.0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! that fixed it thanks! can i ask exactly when does that function get called?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)), this method gets called when window gains or loses focus. Practically, it's called for example on resume of activity, on orientation changes.But it's always called after views are measured and you can get activity size there.